# What does the ^= operator do?

Tags: operators

Hello i was wondering if someone could explain what the ^= operator is doing in this c program? The program is being written for an arm architecture.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <pru_cfg.h>

volatile register uint32_t __R30;
volatile register uint32_t __R31;

void main() {
    volatile uint32_t gpo;

    /* Clear GPO pins */
    gpo = (__R30 & 0xFFFF0000);
    __R30 = gpo;
    
    while(1) {
        gpo = __R30;
        gpo ^= 0xF;
        __R30 = gpo;
        __delay_cycles(100000000); // half-second delay
    }
}
```

If you require any other info, let me know, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, `^` is the bitwise [exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or), and

```c
gpo ^= 0xF;
```

is equivalent to

```c
gpo = gpo ^ 0xF;
```

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_assignment#Compound_assignment for more details about it.

Comment: Perhaps a more concrete explanation that it will toggle only the lower four bits would add something.  It is a more succinct way to express it over the longer form.  In the past, it would produce more efficient code, but generally, the `gpo = gpo ^ 0xf;` will be as efficient with any modern compiler (using SSA).